Nothing outside of you needed
What is this? The answer consists of three words.
→ • ←


< ▢ ▭     ▭

< ▭ ▢     <   

▢ < ▭     ▢

▢ ▭ <     <

▭ ▢ <     ▭

▭ < ▢     ▢


This represents

ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS!

Where

< is scissors, ▭ is paper and ▢ is rock.

The → • ← at the top tells us to look at the middle symbol in the diagram, and indeed the column on the right shows which of the two other symbols is the winner:

< ▢ ▭     ▭ paper beats rock
< ▭ ▢     < scissors beats paper
▢ < ▭     ▢ rock beats scissors
▢ ▭ <     < scissors beats paper
▭ ▢ <     ▭ paper beats rock
▭ < ▢     ▢ rock beats scissors

As for the title

The game is played with your hand, nothing else is needed!


Yup, well done!

each row has 3 symbols. How are you deciding which two are playing? in this answer you have 2 beats 3, 1 beats 3, 3 beats 2 and so on. Why?

@KateGregory, the → • ← tells us the middle symbol is the one playing, and then the symbol on the right is the one that beats the middle one

so it doesn't matter which is on the right or the left?

@KateGregory correct. I'm assuming the reason it's displayed as it is where you pick left or right is the list is just a list off all 6 possible ways to arrange the 3
